# If Expression in XML

Tags: xml, business-process-management

I have this xml file and i want to insert if to it. but when i insert if compiler says element if not expected.  This is my xml file.
[image]

I Want Set If For The Part That Is Mark On the Picture. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

XML does not have expressions.

Some XML languages may include expressions. Such languages will restrict where expressions can be used. I don't know the language you posted (BPEL?) but it doesn't look like it should allow an "if" construct at that point in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

XML doesn't have expression for the same but you can have your own like this

```
<IF attributes>
    <your actions>
<THEN attributes>
    <your actions>
</THEN>
<ELSE attributes>
    <your actions>
</ELSE>
</IF>
```

And parse it accordingly.

Found similar stuff [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061470/if-then-else-using-xml)