# How to write “||”(OR) in XML?

Tags: xml

How do I write the OR keyword in XML?

For example, how do I write this line in XML?

```
#if (define A &amp;&amp; define B) || (define C &amp;&amp; !define D)
```

I am only able to find these: `&lt;` for `<` less than, `&gt;` for `>` greater than, `&amp;` for `&` ampersand, `&apos;` for `'` apostrophe, `&quot;` for `"` quotation mark. How should I change `||` OR?

Comment: What are you talking about? XML does not have logic.

Comment: You could try this but XML is not intended to be used like you describe. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061470/if-then-else-using-xml

Comment: XML isn't a programming language. It doesn't have anything meaning "OR" or "define" or "NOT". It just contains data, to be read by some other program.

Comment: Whatever you're doing, just use a proper XML library (rather than string concatenation). In any case, `|` is not a special char in XML so it doesn't need any special handling.

Comment: xml having logic but i am not able to find other than these all
&lt; < less than
&gt; > greater than
&amp; & ampersand 
&apos; ' apostrophe
&quot; " quotation mark

how should to change OR

Comment: @Dinos_12345 That's a probably misleading link. That other guy was using XML to implement his own language logic.

Comment: Maybe you are confusing "XML" with some other format, or some specific format that happens to be written in XML? Is there a sample of the file you do have that you can show us? Please [edit] your question to include as much detail as possible.

Comment: Is your real question "How do I express a pipe character in XML?". You just type `|`. It doesn't need to be represented by an entity (as `&` does).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I know, but it could help him simulate what he wants.

Comment: @RadhamohanParashar I have [edit]ed your question based on your comment. Please check that this is what you wanted to know. In future, please click "[edit]" under the question to add important details like this in when asked for them.

Comment: @RadhamohanParashar: Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) whichever answer has most helped helped you resolve your problem, or post a follow-up comment explaining how you're still stuck.  You might also consider accepting answers to some of your other questions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Type it between an opening tag and its closing pair:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
#if (define A &amp;&amp; define B) **||** (define C &amp;&amp; !define D)
</foo>
```

Done!

I suspect you're assuming that `&&` needs to be escaped as `&amp;&amp;` because it's the logic AND operator (thus the `||` logic OR operator needs some escaping too). That's wrong. The `&` character needs to be escaped so it's not confused with a character entity, such as `&lt;`. It has nothing to do with operators, something that XML does not really have since it isn't a programming language.

Comment: This answer is also correct (+1), and the anonymous coward downvoter should be ignored.

Answer (score 3):

Certain characters in XML such as `&` and `<` must be escaped (as `&amp;` and `&lt;`) within the content of an XML document so as not to confuse the parser since these characters are used to define the markup.

`||` is not used to define markup in XML and so may appear as itself, unescape, in the content of an XML document.

Therefore, your line,

```
#if (define A &amp;&amp; define B) || (define C &amp;&amp; !define D)
```

may appear as you have it as the value of an element,

```
<e>
  #if (define A &amp;&amp; define B) || (define C &amp;&amp; !define D)
</e>
```

or an attribute:

```
  <e a="#if (define A &amp;&amp; define B) || (define C &amp;&amp; !define D)"/>
```

Comment: Would the anonymous downvoter like to *try* to explain the confusion led to their disapproval?