# How to set TestNG to run which test that available

Tags: java, maven, testng

I have suite of testNG (Maven above) that have tests inside it, I want to run some of the tests meanwhile the others won't run (they can ignored or even failed) - the case is for few mobiles that will be connect to the PC and some that not,
the suite looks like so:

```
    <test name="Redmi 6A">
        <listeners>
            <listener class-name="com.qa.listeners.TestListener" />
        </listeners>
        <parameter name="emulator" value="false" />
        <parameter name="platformName" value="Android" />
        <parameter name="deviceName" value="Redmi 6A" />
        <parameter name="systemPort" value="10000" />
        <parameter name="chromeDriverPort" value="11000" />
        <classes>
            <class name="redmi6A.Installation"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="OnePlus 6 Pro">
        <listeners>
            <listener class-name="com.qa.listeners.TestListener" />
        </listeners>
        <parameter name="emulator" value="false" />
        <parameter name="platformName" value="Android" />
        <parameter name="deviceName" value="onePlus 6Pro" />
        <parameter name="systemPort" value="10000" />
        <parameter name="chromeDriverPort" value="11000" />
        <classes>
            <class name="onePlus6Pro.Installation"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
```

so I want that the code will work if both devices are connected and in other hand only if one of them is connected

Comment: When you start tests, do you know if the device connected? Or you will know this only when tests start to run?

Comment: @MaxDaroshchanka I will know only when tests run - I mean physically I know but the code doesn't know and I don't want to disable it handy

Answer (score 1):

*Option1*

Just delegate testNG xml generation to some pre-build CI step.

Create a class, which e.g. checks adb devices list and includes or excludes some xml parts.

Run the class and generate xml and use it in test run.

*Option2*

Use `IAnnotationTransformListener` to disable tests based on some logic.

You have to define somehow which test depends on which device. In your example, I see you can retrieve this from the class package name. Then you have to check if the device is connected and disable the test if needed.

https://techfortesting.wordpress.com/2019/12/27/iannotation-transformer/

*Note: you have to apply this listener in xml, not in the code. This is because it should be applied in the early stage of TestNG execution.*

Sorry, I've not provided the final code snippets, because it takes time to implement this.

Comment: Thank you, in option 1 how do you call the specific class that is for your config from the running actual class?
About option 2, I will need to add all the tests in same class? because if so, then the report or the video folders won't be created per device?

Comment: For 1 you can create the class with `public static void main` method and run it with
`mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="package.name.ClassName"` and running tests will be the 2nd maven command.

Comment: For option2 - it's not required to put all the test to a single class.. Anyway you able to setup configurations based on your xml and add corresponding @Before/After methods to start and stop video recordings and to create folders as you like. I think you might start from some simple behaviour and adjust it step by step..

Comment: Ok option 2 looks better since it can be worked from inside the code if I understand, even-though that the devops offer to get the parameters from environment variable's and than to send it to the Testng xml via the maven , and than to make an if else something like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061470/if-then-else-using-xml but still I need to see how to work with that listener

Comment: I'll try to add some example with `IAnnotationTransformListener` if I'll have some free time by the end of week. But the result you'll get with this listener - that some tests mentioned in xml just not executed and not visible in reports.

Comment: That is just what I need, and what are the params that it should work from? - I can get them all with ADB from outside

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241200/discussion-between-max-daroshchanka-and-ness).